# MS Access Printing different text in report based on checked/unchecked box

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have an Access app that enters details about applicants. Applicants need to deliver 4 different things via post/mail. So if applicant delivered the things the checkbox is ticked and I have 4 different checkboxes. I have a standardized report that asks applicant to deliver necessary thing.

What I need is to generate in report list of stuff that applicant basically failed to send. So it would go like:

Dear sir/madam,

Etc..Etc..
One of the following is not delivered, or not complete:

1. CheckBox1
2. CheckBox2
3. CheckBox3
4. CheckBox4

So I need the command that would print only checkboxes that are NOT ticked:

1. CheckBox1
2. CheckBox4.

Thanks

Since my knowledge is limited both in Access and in VBA, I can only make a report for each of the situations and then let user select one that suits the situation.

EDIT: What I tried so far was adding IIf statement:

```
="Lot of texts 
" & IIf([CheckBox1];" ";"- MissingCheckBox1") & "
" & IIf([CheckBox2];" ";"- MissingCheckBox2") & "
" & IIf([CheckBox3];" ";"- MissingCheckBox3") & "
" & IIf([CheckBox4];" ";"- MissingCheckBox4") & "
a lot of texts"
```

This does print in report what is missing for 1 and 4, but for 2 and 3 asks me to input something and proceeds to print it in report, regardless if the checkbox is ticked or not.

I have no knowledge on how to make 1,2,3,4 list, thus I have added new row and - as list for items.

EDIT2
Thanks guys for your help. For some reason I did not include checkbox2 and 3 in report builder and that is why it asked to enter value.

Comment: Is each checkbox a Yes/No field in table? Your expression should work without prompts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a function that create the text and deliver that text to the report:

```
Function InfoDelivery(CheckBox1, CheckBox2, CheckBox3, CheckBox4)
    Dim s$
    
    ' Message
    s = "Dear sir/madam,\\Etc..Etc..\\"
    
    ' What to write
    If CheckBox1 And CheckBox2 And CheckBox3 And CheckBox4 Then
        s = s & "You have delivered all item! Well done!!!"
    Else
        s = s & "One of the following is not delivered, or not complete:"
    End If
    
    ' Add text for unchecked checkboxes
    If Not CheckBox1 Then s = s & "\1. CheckBox 1"
    If Not CheckBox2 Then s = s & "\2. CheckBox 2"
    If Not CheckBox3 Then s = s & "\3. CheckBox 3"
    If Not CheckBox4 Then s = s & "\4. CheckBox 4"
    
    ' Replace \ with linebreak
    s = Replace(s, "\", vbCrLf)
    
    ' Return text
    InfoDelivery = s
    
End Function
```

This is how the report looks like in design view:

[image: This is how the report looks like:]

Printed report looks like this:
[image]